# flyway - why can't switch to a newly created schema?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, flyway

I'm having a go with flyway and it looks promising. So, on the root project's `pom.xml` file, I have this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost</url>
        <user>sa</user>
        <password>dbPassword/</password>
        <schemas>
            <schema>schemaA</schema>
            <schema>schemaB</schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

On projectA's and projectB's `pom.xml`, I have this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, on each project's `application.properties` there is the following:

```
#flyway
flyway.baseline-description= #
flyway.baseline-version=1 # version to start migration
flyway.baseline-on-migrate= #
flyway.check-location=false # Check that migration scripts location exists.
flyway.clean-on-validation-error= #
flyway.enabled=true # Enable flyway.
#flyway.encoding= #
#flyway.ignore-failed-future-migration= #
#flyway.init-sqls= # SQL statements to execute to initialize a connection immediately after obtaining it.
flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
#flyway.out-of-order= #
#flyway.placeholder-prefix= #
#flyway.placeholder-replacement= #
#flyway.placeholder-suffix= #
#flyway.placeholders.*= #
flyway.schemas=schemaX
#flyway.sql-migration-prefix=V #
#flyway.sql-migration-separator= #
#flyway.sql-migration-suffix=.sql #
flyway.table= #
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost
flyway.user=sa
flyway.password=dbPassword
flyway.validate-on-migrate= #
```

So, in order to try make it work, here's what I do:

1. create schemaA and schemaB on the database using user `sa` and password `dbPassword`.
2. place at location `[projectA]/src/main/resources/db/migration/`m a file `V1_0_Initialize.sql` which is creates the structure of the tables and populates with standardized data.
3. try to run with the following command: `mvn clean flyway:migrate -DskipTests`

On step 3, I get the error message:

`[INFO] Current version of schema [dbo.schemaA]: null`

`[INFO] Migrating schema [dbo.schemaA] to version 1.0 - Initialize`

And after a few lines:

`[ERROR] Message    : The specified schema name "dbo.schemaA" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.`

If I try to import the script using the DBMS, everything works perfectly.

What am I not seering?

Kind regards,

Comment: Why do you have both the plugin and are using flyway from Spring Boot. You don't need both.

Comment: If I comment out the plugin section, I get this `[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'flyway' in the current project and in the plugin groups (...)`. If I comment out the flyway section from spring boot's application properties, the error is the same as the original question.

Comment: As stated you don't need the plugin, Spring Boot will execute flyway on startup. You use either the plugin or spring boot with flyway integrated, using them both doesn't look like a smart thing to do. The plugin doesn't know anything about your `application.properties` and what you have set in there and spring boot nothing about your maven plugin.

Comment: OK, I understand that I should use one way or the other. I am trying to use the spring boot approach, but it cries out no plugin found and spews out the error.

Comment: Don't use the plugin... When using Spring Boot don't use `mvn flyway:migrate`

Comment: I am not using the plugin anymore. So, I am, on the root project, just issuing `mvn clean compile -DskipTests`. But it does not accesses any of the flyway goals or tries to access the database...

Comment: Make sure you don't have configuration in your pom that tries to execute the plugin as part of the compile (or test) step.

Comment: I don't. So how do I tell spring boot to use flyway?

Comment: You don't, spring boot automatically detects Flyway on the class path and executes the scripts upon starting the application.